# CrmServiceClient IsReady is false and null after calling it previously

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, crm, xrm

If I try to run the code below immediately after running it, the "svc" will be null and it's IsReady property will be false:

```
        string url = "https://NapProd.napster.net/NAPs/";

        string userName = "nappy@napster.net";

        string password = "nap";

        string connectionString = $@"

                            Url = {url};
                            AuthType = AD;
                            Domain = napster;
                            UserName = {userName};
                            Password = {password};
                            RequireNewInstance = True";

        using (var svc = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString))
        {
            WhoAmIRequest request = new WhoAmIRequest();

            WhoAmIResponse response = (WhoAmIResponse)svc.Execute(request);

            Console.WriteLine("Your UserId is {0}", response.UserId);
            Console.WriteLine(svc.IsReady.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");

        }
```

Regular Exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

The following is the StackTrace:

```
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
   at DeploymentDataTester.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Dev\JaqNycapsDataFeed\DeploymentDataTester\Program.cs:line 60
```

The LastCRMError:

```
Unable to Login to Dynamics CRMObject reference not set to an instance of an object.OrganizationWebProxyClient is nullOrganizationWebProxyClient is null
```

Now if I wait a minute or two and run the program again, it works fine. Also I've leveraged using statement to dispose the connection, so not sure what gives or if Dynamics by default times out after a new connection to a minute or so?

Answer (score 1):

I found this post while dealing with a similar issue.  IsReady is false when I expect the connection object to be in good working order.  I've verified the connection string is correct (at least... a functioning url and correct login stuff).  If I remove the test for "IsReady", I get the null exception.  I thought maybe the "using" statement was causing the problem too, so I removed it and just declared the connection object on its own.  That didn't work either.

I found that the password has a semi-colon in it... which causes problems because the connection string thinks that's the end of the password.  You can apparently put single quotes around the password to deal with the semi-colon, but then you need to escape the password with single quotes in it...
https://www.crmanswers.net/2015/04/simplified-connection-with-password.html

But that didn't solve my problem either.  What finally got me past this hurdle is noticing I was accessing the wrong Dynamics CRM sandbox in my code, but the right one when I was testing manually.  Hopefully some part of my process is helpful for figuring out your issue.